# Posterior distribution when it's only known that data belongs to some known interval

Tags: bayesian, posterior, interval-censoring

Suppose we know the prior distribution. When we observe a data point, say $x$, it allows us to form a posterior distribution. I was wondering what if we only know that the data point $x$ belongs to a certain interval, say $x \in (a,b)$. Is there a way to form a posterior distribution? For example, let's say we have a pair of random variables $(X,T) \sim NormalGamma$. We know that our data $x$ belongs to $(a,b)$, where $a<b$, but this is the only information. Can we form a posterior using this information?

I looked at many textbooks, but couldn't find any hint on this. I also searched for a research work on google scholar, but seems that no work has been done on this question. Is anyone aware of any work on this question?

Comment: You have interval-censored data, that could be a useful search term!

Comment: If $(a,b)$ does not depend on $x,$ apply Bayes' Theorem.  Otherwise, please tell us how this interval was determined.

Comment: @whuber. Yes, (a,b) does not depend on x. I tried to apply Bayes' Theorem, but encounterd some issue. Using the NormalGamma example, having the data point x allows me to form the posterior of T, which also allows me to form the posterior of X. I might have missed something, but when taking the integral over (a,b), I was wondering if I need to use the posterior of pdf of X (which is also a function of x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you observe a data point $x$ from some distribution with parameter $\theta$ , the posterior distribution of $\theta$ is

$$p(\theta|X=x) \propto p(X=x|\theta) \pi(\theta) $$

with $\pi(\theta) $ being the prior on $\theta$.

given only the information that $X$ is the interval $[a,b]$, applying Bayes' rule in the same manner means that

$$p(\theta|X \in [a,b]) \propto p(X\in [a,b]|\theta) \pi(\theta) = \int_a^b f(x|\theta)dx \times \pi(\theta)$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can we extend your logic a bit further? Let's say we have 'y~N(x,h)' and both 'x' and 'h' are drawn from known distributions. When we have a data point 'y1', it will allow us to form a posterior for both 'x' and 'h'. If such data point belongs to '[a,b]' and we want to know 'E[x|y1\in[a,b]]', can we use the expression similar with yours? I think knowing a data point y1 (even though it is interval) provides information for both x and h. So, when taking the expectation over y, I guess using 'f(h)' loses some information.

Comment: Yes you can calculate it in the same way